# Clojure zipmap a blank needs to be filled

Tags: clojure, zipmap

```
(testing "zipmap"

  (is (= {:a 1 :b 2} (zipmap [:a :b] '(1 2))))
  (is (= {3 1, 2 2, 1 3} (zipmap [1 2 3] [3 2 1])))
  (is (= {} (zipmap [] [:a :b])))
  (is (= {2 :b, 1 :a} (zipmap [1 2 3] [:a :b])))
```

I solved top 4 questions. But I could not figure out the last one. We need to fill the zipmap part.(I put 2 question marks there). The question is what we need to put there to get this output:

```
{:list '() :map {} :vector [] :set #{}}

(is (= {:list '() :map {} :vector [] :set #{}} (zipmap ? ? )))))
```

This is actually a part of my homework but I really want to know the answer.

Thank you,

Comment: Just remember that `:list`, `'()`, ... `#{}`, are just as much values as `3` and `"Hello, world!"`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that logic but It did not work.

(is (= {:list '() :map {} :vector [] :set #{}} (zipmap [:list :map :vector :set] '('() {} [] #{}) )))))

Thank you for helping tho,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zipmap takes two sequences, one containing all the keys, and the other containing all the values. It produces a map where each key matches the value in the same position in the other list

```
user> (zipmap [:list :map :vector :set] [`() {} [] #{}])
{:set #{}, :vector [], :map {}, :list ()}
```

In this case, your being asked to provide a sequence of keywords and a sequence of empty examples of different types of collections to produce a map of keywords to an example of a collection.

Comment: I tried everything possible, it does not work. It should be exact output. I understood what u said but not enough. I guess. :(